# How to connect to Node Container app via SSH?

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, ssh

Using docker to run a node application i am unable to access it via SSH in the azure portal. I have added an ssh config file and am using apk add openssh. The app runs fine without adding the commands to add SSH. No clue how to get it to work correctly. Getting azure connection refused

```
FROM node:14-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app/

COPY package.json yarn.lock /app/

RUN yarn

ADD . .

RUN yarn build

FROM node:14-alpine as runner
WORKDIR /app/
ENV NODE_ENV=production

COPY --from=builder /app/build /app/
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json /app/yarn.lock /app/
COPY src/database/prisma/schema.prisma /app/prisma/

RUN yarn

COPY docker/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN apk add openssh && echo "root:MyP@ssword1" | chpasswd

#EXPOSE 8080
#CMD node web_server/index.js
EXPOSE 8080 2222
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd &; node web_server/index.js
```

Comment: did you try it locally? is that ok that you expose 2222 instead of ssh default port 22 ?

Comment: Yes according to azure docs 2222 should work https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux

Comment: What service is it running on? VM, ACI, something else?

Comment: It’s running in an azure app service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app runs fine, try to add the followings:

Add a `sshd_config` file to your repository, like the following example.

```
Port            2222
ListenAddress       0.0.0.0
LoginGraceTime      180
X11Forwarding       yes
Ciphers aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
MACs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
StrictModes         yes
SyslogFacility      DAEMON
PasswordAuthentication  yes
PermitEmptyPasswords    no
PermitRootLogin     yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

In your Dockerfile, try to add the following commands:

```
# ssh
COPY docker/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN apk add openssh && echo "root:MyP@ssword1" | chpasswd

COPY sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/

EXPOSE 8080 2222
CMD ["bash","init.sh"]
```

Add `init.sh` in the root folder of your project.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo "Starting SSH ..."
service ssh start
node web_server/index.js
```

Or, change your last code to `CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D", "node web_server/index.js"]`

For more references, see [here1](https://github.com/jgiannuzzi/docker-ssh/blob/master/Dockerfile) and [here2](https://dev.to/s1ntaxe770r/how-to-setup-ssh-within-a-docker-container-i5i)

Comment: This worked but now I am getting SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: All configured authentication methods failedError: when i try and ssh

Comment: Ended up using this   --> COPY docker/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN apk add openssh && echo "root:myPassword1" | chpasswd

COPY init.sh /usr/local/bin/

EXPOSE 8080 2222
RUN /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A 
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd & node web_server/index.js